# JSON and .net Compact Framework (Windows Mobile) with large Strings

Tags: c#, json, compact-framework

I am using Newtonsoft.Json.Compact(Json.NET) for serializing and deserializing my Objects (with Compact Framework 3.5).
My problem is that i get an exception when the Json-string is to large. I tried to update the Newtonsoft.Json but it seems that the newer Versions only work with newer OS. (I am using Windows Mobile 6.5)
Is there an alternative for Newtonsoft.Json which works with the compact Framework or a fix for that problem?

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  while (count > 0)
  {
       count = reader.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
       sb.Append(new string(buffer, 0, count));
  }
  T resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(sb.ToString());`
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please give us the stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: Btw: How large is your string? Maybe you have not enough virtual memory available and you should consider using a database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with dynamic?

`dynamic resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sb.ToString());`